# How to access config files in another package in java

Tags: java

In package B, I want to access config files in package A, the package A is not at my local, and I do not want to add A as my dependency, how can I do this in Java? and how do I pass in this package A? Is that even possible to do so?

My use case is:
I want to access folder X in package A at run time, and this X must exist in all A. This A is not at my local, and I do not know who will this A be ahead of time.

Comment: can you describe your usecase in your question?

Comment: what do you mean with "This A is not at my local". is it on another server? Does ist still host classes that are running within your JVM?

Comment: I mean this A could be any random package in my code base. and this code base is a website.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are not more then directories in the classpath. so the package `com.mycompany.someapp.services` translates to `com/mycompany/someapp/services`.

Now consider how to access a file on the classpath (e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)). Accessing a file from another package is just accessing it from another directory.

Comment: My use case is I want to access this A at run time, so I do not know which package I will access ahead of time.

Comment: So how do you know which file you want to access?

Comment: There is a folder in that package that I want to access, and I know this folder must exist, but I do not know who will this A be.

Comment: and I checked the link you posted, it looks like the file has to be local for the getResourceAsStream() to work, but my use case is this A is not at my local.